# Запись аудио потока в файл Python

Tags: python, web-audio

как можно записать аудио поток (https://5.restream.one/620_0) в аудио файл с помощью Пайтона?
Допустим хочу записать аудио 30секунд в формате mp3
Как-то можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Скопировал с [док-ов](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-usage.html)

```
import urllib3
import time

url = 'https://5.restream.one/1025_1'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', url, preload_content=False)

with open('file.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    begin=time.time()
    while time.time()-begin<30: #30 секунд записи
        data = response.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        out.write(data)

response.release_conn()
```

Comment: Можно немного поподробнее пожалуйста , что за что отвечает?

Comment: @Linar Ismagilov в какой строке трудности? `import urllib3` - это понятно?

Comment: Это понятно, но в идеале чтобы вы расписали каждую строку. И еще я сегодня пробовал, скрипт просто создаёт file.mp3 и никак не записывает аудио потока в него.